# sitemaps.xml in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, sitemap

My website has dynamic content, new links are being created.

my db has a table which pretty much contains all the added urls.

So my question is how importnt is it for me to have sitemaps.xml, and also is there a simple way to build it so that when new links are generated i can  tag it to the end of a sitemap.xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML to create an XML sitemap from your database, then return the sitemap from an action by returning `Content(document.ToString(), "text/xml")`.

Comment: the problem is how do i go about newly added urls, because i dont want it to have to loop through all the urls's everytime the crawler hits it.

Comment: @raklos: You should loop through the URLs every time.  There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: If you really want to, you can run code that writes the file to disk whenever the database is changed, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: if i choose your way, would displaying just the previous weeks links be enough? - as in google will still have records of older links. also instead of linq to xml could i populate the xml within a razor view?

Comment: @raklos: No; you should always list all links.  There is no point in using Razor here; it would be easier to use LINQ to XML to generate a string.  However, you can if you want to.

Comment: I have created this, would telling google my sitemap is located at www.mysite.com/sitemap be enough?(ie without the extension .xml) or do i have to save it as a sitemap.xml file and submit it?

Comment: @rawlos: The extension shouldn't matter at all.  If you want to, though, you can add an extension in the route.

Comment: What if you have 20,000 dynamically generated pages on your site? Should you include them all in the site map, or will Google disregard such a large entry?

Comment: @Drew: Send them all.  Google will handle it.  StackOverflow is an example of a **huge** sitemap.  ​​http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19805/does-stackoverflow-have-a-sitemap/19806#19806

Comment: Thanks very much.  I'll need to tackle this soon for a site I'm building which has a tonne of pages.

Answer (score 2):

It is important for crawlers to be able to crawl your site quicker and with more accurate.

You can create a controller, say siteMapController and in Index add the following

```
 public ActionResult Index() {
        var xmlString =
            "<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd\">";

        xmlString +=
                "<url>" +
               "<loc>Your site</loc>" +
               "<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>" +
               "<priority>0.6</priority>" +
             "</url>" +
           "<url>" +
                    "<loc>Static Link of you site</loc>" + //you can add as many you want
                       "<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>" +
                       "<priority>0.6</priority>" +
                    "</url>" +
                    "<url>";


           //Dynamic links
            xmlString += "<url>" +
                         "<loc>Link of new item"</loc>" +
                         "<lastmod>" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "</lastmod>" +
                         "<changefreq>daily</changefreq>" +
                         "<priority>0.8</priority>" +
                         "</url>";
        }
        xmlString += "</urlset>";
        ViewData["siteMap"] = xmlString;
        return View();
    }
```

save the xml on your server and post the sitemap via this link

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

hope that helps

Comment: What if you have 20,000 dynamically generated pages on your site?  Should you include them all in the site map, or will Google disregard such a large entry.  Also, you should generally avoid building XML via string concatenation.  Either write directly to the response stream or use the XML APIs or a StringBuilder in the worst case.

Comment: okay so this will giveme an xml file at http://www.mysite.com/sitemap/ ? the problem is, when newly created links are added to the db will i have to rerender the entire xml file?